# measure distance between two points in python

Tags: python, performance, geospatial

I'm working in a function that generates isochrones for a project of mine and I'm facing a bottleneck performing some distance calculations.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
def distanciapunto(row, punto):
    try:
        geometriarow = transform(transformer.transform, row["geometry"])
        geometriapunto = transform(transformer.transform, punto)
        distancia = geometriarow.distance(geometriapunto)
        return distancia
    except AttributeError:
        return 10000
dfinterno["distancia"] = dfinterno.apply(lambda row: distanciapunto(row, p), axis=1)
```

Is there a way to make this faster?

Minimal reproducible example:

> ```
> from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
> from functools import partial
> import pyproj
> from shapely.ops import transform
> import pandas as pd
>
> def distanciapunto(row, punto, transformer):
>     try:
>         geometriarow = transform(transformer, row["geometry"])
>         geometriapunto = transform(transformer, punto)
>         distancia = geometriarow.distance(geometriapunto)
>         return distancia
>     except AttributeError:
>         return 10000
>
> dfinterno = pd.DataFrame({
>     "geometry": [LineString([(0, 0), (3, 4)]), LineString([(2, 2), (5, 6)]), LineString([(1, 1), (4, 5)])]
> })
> transformer = partial(pyproj.transform, pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326'), pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:22185'))
> p = Point(1, 1)    
> dfinterno["distancia"] = dfinterno.apply(lambda row: distanciapunto(row, p, transformer), axis=1)
>
> print(dfinterno["distancia"])
> ```

Comment: Rather than returning a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) I would really like to see `INFINITE_DISTANCE = 10_000` defined. And [pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) asks that you spell it `distancia_punto`, `geometria_row`, and so on. But you were mostly interested in performance. Thank you kindly for the MRE, that really is quite helpful. Perhaps you'd like to expand it so it crunches for ten seconds and then gives a performance metric?

Answer (score 1):

General (non-[performance](/questions/tagged/performance)) review:

- Don't run words together like that in identifiers.  [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) says you should use underscores as word separators; e.g. `distancia_punto` rather than <s>`distanciapunto`</s>.
- The function's docstring is missing.  It needs to describe the meaning of the arguments, and also the global variable (`transformer`) that is referenced.
- Prefer to pass `transformer` as an argument rather than using a global variable.
- Choose a better exceptional return (10 000 metres is a plausible distance between two points on Earth; 50 000 is impossible; `None` clearly distinguishes from an actual value).  Better, don't catch the exception and instead allow the caller to decide what should happen.
- The final line (outside the function) references another global into which I have no insight.

Comment: Thanks @greybeard - that's a constant hazard of switching between languages.